# Autokriging spatial data

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial-interpolation, automap

I'm trying to use a kriging function to create vertical maps of chemical parameters in an ocean transect, and I'm having a hard time getting started.

My data look like this:

```
horiz=rep(1:5, 5)
depth=runif(25)
value = horiz+runif(25)/5
df <- data.frame(horiz, depth, value)
```

The `autoKrige` function in the `automap` package looks like it should do the job for me but it takes an object of class `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. As far as I can tell, the function `spTransform` in package `rgdal` creates `SpatialPointsDataFrame` objects, but there are two problems:

- OSX binaries of this [aren't available](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) from CRAN, and my copy of RStudio running on OXS 10.7 doesn't seem to be able to install it, and
- This function seems to work on lat/long data and correct distance values for the curvature of the Earth. Since I'm dealing with a vertical plane (and short distances, scale of hundreds of meters) I don't want to correct my distances.

There's an excellent discussion of kriging in R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047870/plotting-interpolated-data-on-map), but due to the issues listed above I don't quite understand how to apply it to my specific problem.

I want a matrix or dataframe describing a grid of points with interpolated values for my chemical parameters, which I can then plot (ideally using ggplot2). I suspect that the solution to my problem is considerably easier than I'm making it out to be.

Comment: You should specify your version of MacOS. If it is less than 10.6.x (as mine is and as is suggested by your incorrect claim of "no binaries available") then you are probably out of luck as far as 'rgdal' goes.

Comment: Edited question to reflect that I'm using OSX 10.7. I can't find the binaries for rgdal at CRAN (per the link) - are they available somewhere else? - Oh, @Paul Hiemstra mentions where they are.

Comment: See my answer for a link to rgdal binaries for mac, but I doubt you need them for this particular problem. Although rgdal is a great to have nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there a a few question you want answered:

1. The `spTransform` function does not create SPDF's, but transforms between projections. To create a SPDF you can use a simple `data.frame` as a start. To transform `df` to a SPDF:

   ```
   coordinates(df) = c("horiz", "depth")
   ```
2. OS X binaries of `rgdal` can be found at [http://www.kyngchaos.com](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks). But I doubt if you need rgdal.
3. `spTransform` can operate on latlong data, but also on projected data. But I do not think you need rgdal, or `spTransform`, see also point 1.
4. After you create the SPDF using point 1, you can use [the info at the post you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047870/plotting-interpolated-data-on-map) to go on.

Comment: could you include the package that contains `coordinates()` in your answer? Had no idea it was that easy!

Comment: It is from the sp package, which also provides the SPDF.