# Smoothing of "spatial" data

Tags: r, spatial, smoothing

I have 2 variables `x` and `y` which are Cartesian coordinates at [0,1], and `z` is the value of a (continuous) variable at these coordinates. The `z` vector has some important outliers

```
x<-sample(seq(0,1,0.001), replace=F)
y<-sample(seq(0,1,0.001), replace=F)
z<-runif(1001,min=0,max=1)
z[100]<-8;z[400]<-16;z[800]<-4
```

These outliers I would like to emphasize when presenting these data in a `filled.contour`

I have used until now

```
library(akima)
a<-interp(x,y,z)
filled.contour(a$x,a$y,a$z)
```

But I am not happy with this linear interpolation. For example (the outliers do not show up correctly).

I am thinking what I need is a some kind nearest neighbor "spatial" smoothing of z (based on the x,y location). Can anyone help or pinpoint to data/examples/packages/code that could help me? I would prefer a base R solution but if ggplot2 or lattice can do my job it would be fine. Any other idea/proposal of better visualization would be also welcomed.

Comment: You could try spline interpolation, e.g., `a<-interp(x,y,z,linear=FALSE,xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length = 200),yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length = 200));
filled.contour(a$x,a$y,a$z,color.palette=terrain.colors)`.

Comment: I dont know how to understand the key values (z range) when I use spline. In this example linear=T give a range of [0,14] as in the data, but linear=F gives a range of (-100,100)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out @Paul Heimstra's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047870/plotting-interpolated-data-on-map). They suggest thin plate spline interpolation from the [fields](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fields/fields.pdf) package. If kriging is right for you, the package [automap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/automap/automap.pdf) may be useful.

If you're concerned with the interpolation of geographic values, it's worth mentioning [DG Rossiter's online/free course on Geostatistics and Open-source statistical computing](http://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/teach/degeostats.html).

Answer (score 5):

Thin plate splines, or the Tps() function, from the fields package is a your ticket.  The model results must then be placed into the predictSurface() function from the same package to generate smoothed spatial data.  Just a few lines of code is all you need:

```
test.spline <- Tps(data.frame(x,y), z)
new.grid <- predictSurface(test.spline, nx = 200, ny = 200)
image(new.grid)
```

The nature of the data will define how fine a grid is appropriate.  You control this with nx and ny arguments in predictSurface().  In this example, increased grid resolution has no impact.  With real spatial data, smoothing with a high-res surface can be dramatic.  Check function help for more details.