# R plot grid value on maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, lattice

I have several file with the following format: lat,lon,value. I would like to plot a colored grid map with such value for each one of the lat,lon point and overlapping it over the EU map.

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are roughly two options: one using the lattice and sp package and the other using the ggplot2 package:

## lattice / sp

First you have to transform your data to a `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` (provided by the sp-package), assuming your data is called `df`:

```
require(sp)
gridded(df) = c("lat","lon")
```

and then plotting:

```
spplot(df, "value")
```

overlaying additional information such as country boundaries can be done using the `sp.layout` argument:

```
spplot(df, "value", sp.layout = list("sp.lines", cntry_boundaries))
```

where `cntry_boundaries` is a `SpatialLines(DataFrame)`, or `SpatialPolygons(DataFrame)`. Reading a polygonset into R can be done using the `rgdal` package, or the `maptools` package (`readShapeLines`).

## ggplot2

I personally prefer using `ggplot2` over `spplot`. `ggplot2` is more flexible and has a more clear syntax. Note that `ggplot2` works with normal `data.frame`'s, and not with the spatial objects of the sp-package.

A minimal example would look something like:

```
ggplot(aes(x = lat, y = lon), data = df) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_path(data = cntry_boundaries)
```

For more information see these earlier answers of mine:

- [Plotting interpolated data on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047870/plotting-interpolated-data-on-map/10058844#10058844)
- [Average values of a point dataset to a grid dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563334/average-values-of-a-point-dataset-to-a-grid-dataset/8563683#8563683)

Comment: This answer is so good! Had  the same problem, and was guided by this answer to solve my problem. +1